# como enviar una peticion multipart con postman

Tags: express

necesito enviar un archivo csv mediante postman y que cuando se haga la peticion el archivo se cargue un ana carpeta de mi proyecto
estoy trabajando con node.js Express

Comment: [Upload a file via POST request](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/documentation/13455110-00378d5c-5b08-4813-98da-bc47a2e6021d)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.